# Run psql query and get output ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"

Tags: bash

I am trying Run psql query and get output ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"

Run query from psql

```
 ➤ psql://postgres@dev-postgresql-95-1:5432/mydb 

# CREATE FUNCTION f_showfile(myfile text) RETURNS text AS $x$ BEGIN RETURN pg_read_file(myfile, 0, 100000); END; $x$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL SECURITY DEFINER;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Run query from bash

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -d mydb -c "CREATE FUNCTION f_showfile(myfile text) RETURNS text AS $x$ BEGIN RETURN pg_read_file(myfile, 0, 100000); END; $x$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL SECURITY DEFINER;"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: ... FUNCTION f_showfile(myfile text) RETURNS text AS $ BEGIN RE...
```

How correct run psql query in bash?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you send contains the following :

```
$x$
```

which is expanded by bash as the content of the variable `$x`. As `$x` is empty, `$x$` is replaced by `$`. You can avoid the variable expansion by using simple quotes instead of double quotes :

```
psql -d mydb -c 'CREATE FUNCTION f_showfile(myfile text) RETURNS text AS $x$ BEGIN RETURN pg_read_file(myfile, 0, 100000); END; $x$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL SECURITY DEFINER;'
```